# Accessing one table with multiple names

Tags: mysql

I have a table like tbl_example. 
I want to access the same table with different names like tbl_a or tbl_b. Is there any way to do so in MySQL?

adding an example
Suppose I have a table tbl_A and 5 users with following userid:
1: user1
2: user2
3: user3
4: user4
5: user5

And I pick the table name dynamically for each user:  tbl_ e.g: tbl_user1
In current scenario I have created 5 different tables with same data , but I do not want to redundant my db with multiple tables with same data. 
So is there any way to use this single table with 5 different names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view to "hide" the original table name:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS 
    SELECT * from original_table
```

Comment: Hi Juergen the thing is I do not want to share the main table name so the other user will not know that there is a table with name tbl_example. the table name shared with the other user can be anything like tbl_a or t1

Comment: @Nikk: You could create a *View* with the name you like.